Alien that bleeds rainbow blood
I have been looking for nearly ten years still no clue. I remember in early 1990s watching a movie where a wounded human looking alien with white eyes and no pupils dripping rainbow blood from stomach inside a car, and giving his weaponary to the driver he just met and tells him something then dies in an explosion of white light, leaving behind only the weapon.
Then the story goes with that person with alien weapon hunting or being hunted by human looking alien of seemingly different species, this time with some kind of hook that shoots out to collect blood from the neck of human victims and automatically collect them inside a row of test tubes hidden in its stomach pouch, which he regularly check for blood stock. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Since everything matches I Come In Peace from 1990 (except the wounded alien's blood was kinda white and blue, and not exactly rainbow colored), I marked it as a duplicate. If this isn't the right film, please let me know.
